# Computing distance by time and speed in java

Tags: java

I have multiple records with speed (in KM/h) and time (in Date) and i would like to know what was total distance traveled. Time and speed is changing. Is there any java algorythm for this?

Comment: Java algorithm? First read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Mathematical algorithms, perhaps?

Comment: It is possible to approximate based on some assumption (e.g. constant acceleration), but not calculate exactly (since not all information is available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data points of speed and time you need to work out the average speed between points (this may not be accurate, but its the best you can do with the data) and multiply by the time. Note that I have used seconds as the time measurement. You say you have Date, so you should be able to convert easily, probably best to use miliseconds if your times are close together.

Lets say you have the following data points;

```
Time speed
0    12
4    15
7    13
11   18
17   21
```

The average speed between point 1 and 2 is;

```
12 + 15 / 2 = 13.5
```

and the time difference is 4 seconds. The best calculation you can make is that the distance travelled between these data points is

```
4 * 13.5 * (1000 / 3600) = 15 metres
```

the (1000 / 3600) bit is converting km/h into m/s.

Your algorithm needs to perform the same calculation with each pair of data points and add up the total distance travelled.

Comment: Thanks this looks like same algorythm like Laky posted here. Thanks very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply calculate for each consequent pair of values this:

```
distance = previousVelocity * timeDifference + (currentVelocity - previousVelocity) * timeDifference / 2
```

Where `timeDifference = currentTime - previousTime`.

Then sum it all up and there you go. This is assuming constant acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: Thanks becouse this is real data that i use from car i assume that acceleration and deceleration is constant. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined "Java algorithm" for this. You have to calculate the entire distance by adding up all `ds = v * dt`. `ds` is delta distance, `v` is the velocity and `dt` delta time. A loop will do fine. 
Other than that, you could determine the average speed and do one multiplication.

Comment: @nhahtdh You are right. I'll edit it immediately. No reason for a downvote :)

Comment: If you assume constant acceleration between 2 data points, then the distance is (vprev + vcurrent) / 2 * delta time. It doesn't make sense to do (vcurrent - vprev) * delta time.

Comment: This assumes that the speed increases and decreases in sudden hops. But may be good enough for the approximation needed. More info from Amsik would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to plot the curve between the points (x axis = time, y axis = speed) and calculate the area under that graph. Obviously this will vary depending on your choice of interpolation (straight line, bezier curve, cubic spline etc.)

[This](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Interpolation.html) looks like an interesting list of interpolation libraries.

There also seems to be a [javax.media.jai.Interpolation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/Interpolation.html) component available.